# Como acessar o valor de um ponteiro dentro de uma função no main?

Tags: c, ponteiro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *Notas_Baixas(float Vet[],int Total_De_Notas, int *Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas){
    int i;
    *Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < Total_De_Notas; i++){
        if(Vet[i] < 5){
        *Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas ++;
        }
    }
    return &Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas;
}
int main(){
int Numero_De_Alunos, Nota, i;
float *Notas;
printf("Digite a quantidade de alunos da turma : ");
scanf("%d",&Numero_De_Alunos);
Notas = (int *) malloc((Numero_De_Alunos * 2) * sizeof(int)); 
printf("\n");
int Cont_De_Aluno = 1;
for(i = 0; i < (Numero_De_Alunos * 2); i+=2){
    printf("Digite a nota 1 do aluno %d : ", Cont_De_Aluno);
    scanf("%f", &Notas[i]);
    printf("Digite a nota 2 do aluno %d : ", Cont_De_Aluno);
    scanf("%f", &Notas[i+1]);
    Cont_De_Aluno ++;
    printf("\n");
}
for(i = 0; i < (Numero_De_Alunos * 2); i++){
    printf("%f ", Notas[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int Pega_Nota_Baixa;
int *Numero_De_Notas_Baixas = Notas_Baixas(Notas,(Numero_De_Alunos * 2),&Pega_Nota_Baixa);
printf("\nQuantidade de notas baixas pelo retorno = %d",Numero_De_Notas_Baixas);
printf("\nQuantidade de notas baixas pelo ponteiro = %d", Pega_Nota_Baixa);
return 0;
}
```

Preciso acessar o contador ponteiro Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas dentro da função Notas_Baixas no main, só que a saida é sempre 0.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Preciso acessar o contador ponteiro Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas dentro
> da função Notas_Baixas no main, só que a saida é sempre 0.

O pouco que deu a entender do seu problema, você está recebendo um ponteiro para `Pega_Nota_Baixa` na função `Notas_Baixas`, manipulando o seu valor e retornando um outro ponteiro apontando para ele.

De toda forma, se este for o seu problema, você não precisa retornar o dado de volta uma vez que está enviando ele como parâmetro da função. O código abaixo é um exemplo disso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Notas_Baixas(int *Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas){
    *Pont_Numero_De_Notas_Baixas = 5;
}

int main() {
    int Pega_Nota_Baixa;
    Notas_Baixas(&Pega_Nota_Baixa);

    printf("%d", Pega_Nota_Baixa);
    return 0;
}
```